# Drupal: Panels argument (node title instead of node id)

Tags: drupal, view, arguments, panels

I'm working with drupal and the modules views and panels, and its with the last i got stuck.. i got my view setup with passing the node title as an argument, but the panels 2.xx module only supports node ID.

So i'm searching for a module or any other solution to pass the node title as an argument  to the panel itself.

How its supposed to be working in the perfect world:
http://mywebsite.com/bands/bandname

bandname is the node title, but at the same time also the argument that i pass to views.. Since panels don't support the title, i ask if there is a way to keep the 'bandname', but use the nid for displaying the data? So when a users goes to http://mywebsite.com/bandname it loads the nid in the view, but keeps the url alias.

Thx in advance!